# show text in select box in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, text

I have a select box and according the selected value I want to show the value in next selected box. My code is like:

```
$('#category').change(function(){
        var cat_val = $('#category option:selected').text();
        if(cat_val == 'Online'){
            $('#workshop-row').hide();
            $('#bu_id').val(22);
        }else{
            $('#workshop-row').show();
        }
    });
```

By doing `$('#bu_id').val(22);` I can get the value. But I need to set the text not val() like

```
$('#bu_id option:selected').text("Online");
```

That means if I select Online from the first select box then in the 2nd select box, the value whose text is Online will be selected.

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: http://www.codegateway.com/2012/03/set-selected-option-by-text-of.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will select the option which has the text value  **cat_val**

```
   $("#bu_id option:contains(" + cat_val + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: @Mausumi , you are welcome , the thing is try to search before you ask a question , actually i also searched for this answer , and i found that article that i have posted above , search and search , that will make you a better programmer :D :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bu_id').html(22);

or 

$('#bu_id').text(22);
```

Comment: also you can use `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tj5tt/)**

```
$('#category').change(function(){
            var cat_val = $('#category option:selected').text();
            if(cat_val == 'Online'){
                $('#workshop-row').hide();
                $('#bu_id').val(cat_val);           
            }else{
                $('#workshop-row').show();
            }
        });
```